# NoClassDefFoundError in Spring Objenesis in JBoss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jvm

> I'm sorry for the long post ahead but it's required for understanding
>   the problem correctly in my opinion

**Context**

I'm using a Spring Multi Module application on Jboss EAP with all of the dependency jars in a Jboss Module (shared library):

`<dependencies>
    <module name="com.etcbase.sharedlib" slot="4.3.14" export="true" meta-inf="export" />
    <module name="org.jboss.jts" />
    </dependencies>`

Along with that I'm using [Hotswap-Agent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent) which uses spring objenesis for it's functionality, asin the following method for creating a spring proxy for hot-swapping:

```
private Method getProxyCreationMethod(Object bean) throws CannotCompileException, NotFoundException {
    if (getCp(loader).find("org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor") != null) {
        if (createSpringProxy == null) {
            synchronized (springLock) {
                if (createSpringProxy == null) {

                    ClassPool cp = getCp(loader);

                    springCallback = buildProxyCallbackClass(SPRING_PACKAGE, cp);
                    springNamingPolicy = buildNamingPolicyClass(SPRING_PACKAGE, cp);

                    springProxy = buildProxyCreaterClass(SPRING_PACKAGE, springCallback, springNamingPolicy, cp);

                    createSpringProxy = springProxy.getDeclaredMethods()[0];

                }
            }
        }
        return createSpringProxy;
```

Now after creating the SpringProxy, it uses it in the following for java reflection:

```
private Object doCreate(Object beanFactry, Object bean, Class<?>[] paramClasses, Object[] paramValues) {
    try {
        Method proxyCreater = getProxyCreationMethod(bean);
        if (proxyCreater == null) {
            return bean;
        } else {
            return proxyCreater.invoke(null,beanFactry, bean, paramClasses, paramValues);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {


        LOGGER.warning("Can't create proxy for " + bean.getClass().getSuperclass()
                + " because there is no default constructor,"
                + " which means your non-singleton bean created before won't get rewired with new props when update class.");
        return bean;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | CannotCompileException | NotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Creating a proxy failed", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

So after the proxyCreater (from SpringProxy method) tries to use the invoke functionality. Then it throws the InvocationTargetException and prints the warning that it won't be able to hotswap the beans since there is no default constructor for it.

***Problem*** :
The root cause of the issue after debugging is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.util.UnsafeUtils
```

Complete Debug Log from above:

```
    HOTSWAP AGENT: 10:49:35.672 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.EnhancerProxyCreater) - Can't create proxy for class com.etcbase.sfc.util.IdManagerImpl because there is no default constructor, which means your non-singleton bean created before won't get rewired with new props when update class.
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) HOTSWAP AGENT: 10:49:35.673 WARNING (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.EnhancerProxyCreater) - error
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.EnhancerProxyCreater.doCreate(EnhancerProxyCreater.java:114)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.EnhancerProxyCreater.create(EnhancerProxyCreater.java:83)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.EnhancerProxyCreater.createProxy(EnhancerProxyCreater.java:79)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.ProxyReplacer.register(ProxyReplacer.java:85)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
10:49:35,673 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
10:49:35,675 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
10:49:35,676 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
10:49:35,677 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) Caused by: org.springframework.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.util.UnsafeUtils
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.objenesis.SpringObjenesis.newInstantiatorOf(SpringObjenesis.java:149)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.objenesis.SpringObjenesis.newInstance(SpringObjenesis.java:100)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at HotswapAgentSpringBeanProxy_1796692748.create(HotswapAgentSpringBeanProxy_1796692748.java)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   ... 92 more
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.util.UnsafeUtils
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.sun.UnsafeFactoryInstantiator.<init>(UnsafeFactoryInstantiator.java:43)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:98)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   at org.springframework.objenesis.SpringObjenesis.newInstantiatorOf(SpringObjenesis.java:125)
10:49:35,678 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19)   ... 94 more
```

It seems from the above that the spring obejenisis Unsafe utils can not be accessed by the current classloader of Jboss(which here it seems is JbossModuleLoader), and apart from that I checked the UnsafeUtils in it's respective jar which is inside the Jboss Module is used for all jars.

I will link the issue that I created on github as it might help out but this is all what I could know.

Is there someway to locate the unsafeutils through another classloader or is this another issue?

**[Github Issue for this](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/275)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/275#issuecomment-445225662)

> To solve "Could not initialize class org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.util.UnsafeUtils" issue, please add followings to your jboss module.xml file. UnsafeUtils class has a static initialization block that references to sun.misc.Unsafe.

```
<dependencies>
        ....
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="true" >
            <imports>
                       <include path="sun/misc/Unsafe" />
            </imports>
        </module>
 </dependencies>
</module>
```